# Will firing select query on empty table after every 5 millisecond creates any issue?

Tags: .net, linq, .net-core, background-service

**Technology:** We are using .net core 5, sql in our project.

**Background:** We have a BackgroundService which has method ProcessMessage() which has lock(), this method checks whether lock is on or not, if lock is not on then we make it on and fire a select query(it contains 1 join) and do some processing on the data which we got in select query. After processing we release the lock. This select query has configurable limit.

We call ProcessMessage in StartAsyn() through Timer after every 5 milliseconds so select query will be fired only if lock is not on means if that thread is not already processing some data.

There is possibility that sometimes there are no rows in the table but still ProcessMessage will fire select query after every 5 milliseconds. so a senior person suggested us to have IN memory queue with max size 1 and have new method which will keep checking are there any new records in table if yes the add message to in memory queue and ProcessMessage should only execute when this IN memory queue has a message.

I feel this solution will be a bigger overhead than firing select query when there is no data.

**Question:**

1. Please guide me on this, I mean whether existing code is correct one or new solution suggested by senior is correct? or is there any other way to deal with this situation ?
2. what is heavy operation(overhead) between below:

   1. keep firing LINQ query .Any() if it is true then fire select query.
   2. Keep firing select LINQ query without checking are there any record in table or not?

Answer (score 0):

- Windows do not guarantee 5 msec interval, usually it is 10-15 msec
- Query to database is far far way more than 10 msec.

With such constraints you can drop timer and just introduce *infinite* loop. And you will not need lock. Exception is if you have two background services in cluster.

It depends but, but usually you do not need to call `Any`, always call full query. `Any` will do extra not needed work.